# How would one create scatterplots based on characteristics in multiple columns of a data frame?

Tags: r, plot

```
age <- rnorm(100, 0:100)
freq <- rnorm(100, 0:1)
char1<-stringi::stri_rand_strings(100, length = 1, pattern = "[abc]")
char2<-stringi::stri_rand_strings(100, length = 1, pattern = "[def]")
char3<-stringi::stri_rand_strings(100, length = 1, pattern = "[def]")
char3<-stringi::stri_rand_strings(100, length = 1, pattern = "[ghi]")
dftest <- data.frame(age, freq, char1, char2, char3)
dflist <- list(dftest, dftest, dftest, dftest, dftest)
```

This creates a sample data frame that demonstrates the problem I am having.

I would like to create scatterplots for age vs freq for each of the data frames in this list, but I want a different color for the points based on the value in columns "char#". I also need a separate trend line for values in each of these separate characteristics.

I also want to be able to do this based on combinations of different characteristics from different char columns. An example of this is 3*3=9 separate colors for each of the combinations, each with a different trend line.

How would this be done?

I hope this was reproducible and clear enough. I have only posted a few times, so I am still getting used to the format.

Thanks!

Comment: In the data you provided, the list of data frames are all identical, so even if you colored them differently, you'd only see one set of points. Assuming you have real data that looks different than this, you want to first add an id column to each data frame, then `rbind` them all together, and then map color to `id`. For your provided example, your ids would be 1-5

Comment: Have a look at ggplot2. Sounds optimal for that issue. Try to use facets.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by creating a data frame that will allow us to show points with different colors:

```
df2 <- data.frame(age=rnorm(200,0:100),
  freq=rnorm(200,0:1),id=rep(1:2,each=100))
```

Then we can `plot` like so:

```
plot(dflist2$age,dflist2$freq, col=dflist2$id, pch=16)
```

We set `col` (color) equal to `id` (this would represent each data frame). `pch` is the point type (solid dots).

Answer (score 0):

You can try `dplyr` for data preparing and `ggplot` for plotting. All functions are loaded via the tidyverse package:

```
library(tidyverse)
# age vs freq plus trendline for char1
as.tbl(dftest) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(age, freq, color=char1)) +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]

```
# age vs freq plus trendline for combinations of char columns
as.tbl(dftest) %>% 
  unite(combi, char1, char2, char3, sep="-") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(age, freq, color=combi)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
# no plot as too many combinations make the plot  to busy
dflist %>% 
  bind_rows( .id = "df_source") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(age, freq, color=char1)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap(~df_source)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have mentioned this in the question, but is it possible to display the Spearman correlation p-value and rho of each of the linear models on the graph itself?

Comment: Yes this is possible. Have a look at the `ggpubr` or `ggsignify` packages. Note, that `lm` is a parametric method.